# How to add respective columns from different database to compare with another database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of product information and want to add another column to compare with the column `seller name`. To add this column I need to go back to the original table in a different database. My table contains thousands of rows and can't be done manually.

Can you help me to figure it out?

Here is the my table:

| name | sku | seller name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iPhone 11+ | 1234567 | roselife |
| samsung s20 | 1234567 | Bm12 |
| iPhone 12 pro | 547382 | Tech life |
| MacBook Air | 9685732 | Mainland |

I want to take seller name from the table below to match the original seller name

| name | sku | seller name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iPhone 11+ | 1234567 | RoseLife |
| samsung s20 | 1234567 | BM12 |
| iPhone 12 pro | 547382 | Tech&life |
| MacBook Air | 9685732 | Main-land |

How to take the seller column from table 2 and add it to the first table for the respected product ?

so the final output will be :

| name | sku | seller name | seller name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iPhone 11+ | 1234567 | roselife. | RoseLife |
| samsung s20 | 1234567 | Bm12 | BM12 |
| iPhone 12 pro | 547382 | Tech life | Tech&life |
| MacBook Air | 9685732 | Mainland. | Main-land |

Comment: Show your "table2" data example which includes all values shown in desired output.

Comment: thanks for the response , I have added the output